# Given the matrix $A^k$, how to get $A^{k+1}$?

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

Given: $$A^k = \left(\begin{array}{rr} \cos kx & \sin kx \\ -\sin kx & \cos kx\end{array}\right)$$

$$A^{k+1} \overbrace{=}^? \left(\begin{array}{rr} \cos kx & \sin kx \\ -\sin kx & \cos kx\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{rr} \cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x\end{array}\right) \\ = \left(\begin{array}{rr} \cos kx \cos x-\sin kx \sin x & \cos kx\sin x+\sin kx\cos x \\ -\sin kx \cos x+\cos kx (-\sin x) & \cos kx\cos x-\sin kx \sin x\end{array}\right)\\=\left(\begin{array}{rr} \cos (k+1)x & \sin (k+1)x \\ -\sin (k+1)x & \cos (k+1)x\end{array}\right) $$

How? I really don't understand the final part... 
How can for exp.

$$
(-\sin kx)(\cos x) + (\cos kx)(-\sin x)=-\sin (k+1)x
$$

I don't understand much English.

Comment: Have a look at the formulas for $\sin(a+b)$ and $\cos(a+b)$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: Please don't type in ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$
\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b = \cos (a+b)\\
\sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a = \sin (a+b)
$$

---

to remember this:

if the vector $e_a$ of coordinates $(\cos a, \sin a)$ then
$$ \cos a\cos (-b) + \sin a \sin (-b) =
e_a\cdot e_{-b} = \cos(a-(-b))
$$